# How come this particular string filtering does not work in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Why does this work:

`iex(9)> Enum.filter(["lowks", "kian", "seong"], fn(x) -> x == "lowks" end)

["lowks"]`

While this does not:

`iex(5)> Enum.filter(String.split("low kian seong"), fn(x) -> x == "lowks" end)
[]`

Is it because I am filtering the function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you have a typo in the second example. It should be *lowks* not *low*.

```
iex(1)> Enum.filter(String.split("lowks kian seong"), fn(x) -> x == "lowks" end)
["lowks"]
```

Comment: Because it's so much nicer looking: `"lowks kian seong" |> String.split |> Enum.filter &(&1 == "lowks")`